# Aggregate modis list files by month

Tags: r-raster

I am looking for a more efficient way of separating each year from the time series (2002-2016) by month. I've done it by hand, but it takes a lot.

```
mypath<-"D:/SNOWL"
myras<-list.files(path=mypath,pattern = glob2rx("*.tif$"), 
                    full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

> myras
   [1] "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002001.tif" "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002002.tif"
   [3] "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002003.tif" "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002004.tif"
   [5] "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002005.tif" "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002006.tif"
   [7] "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002007.tif" "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002008.tif"
   [9] "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002009.tif" "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002010.tif"
  [11] "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002011.tif" "D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A2002012.tif"

serie<-orgTime(myras, nDays = "asIn", begin ="2002-01-01",end = "2016-12-31", pillow = 75, pos1 = 13, pos2 = 19)
filter<-serie$inputLayerDates 

> filter
   [1] "2002-01-01" "2002-01-02" "2002-01-03" "2002-01-04" "2002-01-05"
   [6] "2002-01-06" "2002-01-07" "2002-01-08" "2002-01-09" "2002-01-10"
  [11] "2002-01-11" "2002-01-12" "2002-01-13" "2002-01-14" "2002-01-15"
  [16] "2002-01-16" "2002-01-17" "2002-01-18" "2002-01-19" "2002-01-20"
  [21] "2002-01-21" "2002-01-22" "2002-01-23" "2002-01-24" "2002-01-25"
  [26] "2002-01-26" "2002-01-27" "2002-01-28" "2002-01-29" "2002-01-30"
  [31] "2002-01-31" "2002-02-01" "2002-02-02" "2002-02-03" "2002-02-04"
  [36] "2002-02-05" "2002-02-07" "2002-02-08" "2002-02-09" "2002-02-10"
  [41] "2002-02-11" "2002-02-12" "2002-02-13" "2002-02-14" "2002-02-15"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Ok, let's try a full size example and see if it's working for you:

```
# Here we generate filenames as returned from `list.files`:


rm(list = ls())

myras <- sapply(1:5465, function(i) paste0('D:/SNOWL/MOYDSL10A1.A',sample(2000:2016,1),sample(c(paste0('00',1:9),paste0('0',10:99),100:365),1),'.tif'))

head(myras)


# Let's extract the timestamps

tstmps <- regmatches(myras,regexpr('[[:digit:]]{7}',myras))

head(tstmps,50)

# And now convert the timestamps to dates 

dates <- as.Date(as.numeric(substr(tstmps,5,7)) - 1, origin = paste0(substr(tstmps,1,4),"-01-01"))

head(dates,10)


# Last step is to sort the files by month

#check months
print(month.name)

myras_byM = sapply(month.name,function(x) myras[months(dates) == x])

head(myras_byM$January)
head(myras_byM$February)
head(myras_byM$March)
head(myras_byM$April)
head(myras_byM$May)
head(myras_byM$June)
head(myras_byM$July)
head(myras_byM$August)
head(myras_byM$September)
head(myras_byM$October)
head(myras_byM$November)
head(myras_byM$December)
```

---

---

You can easily get the date from your filename, if you have a consistent naming convention.

In your case, I see the files are ordered by year and day of the year. So just strip the date from the filename, and then you can filter it by whatever you need. To do this I'm using regular expressions. In this case, I'm interested in the date and DOY string, which should always be 7 numbers. The corresponding RE is therefore `[[:digit:]]{7}`, which means 7 consecutive digits. `regexpr` finds the matches and `regmatches` returns them.

```
dts <- regmatches(myras,regexpr('[[:digit:]]{7}',myras))
```

Then you just use `substring` to extract the digits you need (this method assumes it's always 4 digits for year followed by 3 for DOY) and convert it to a date:

```
dts <-as.Date(as.numeric(substr(dts,5,7)) - 1, origin = paste0(substr(dts,1,4),"-01-01"))
```

That would give you the variable of `filter` you have in your example.

If you then want to sort the entire time series by month, you could use sapply or lapply with the built-in names `month.name`. The base function `months` will return you the name of the month for a given date:

```
myras_byMonth <- sapply(month.name,function(x) myras[months(dts) == x])
```

Hope I understood your question correctly and this was what you were looking for.

Best,

Val

Comment: Thanks, the first two lines work ok but the third one throws this to me      > myras_byMonth 
$January
character(0)

$February
character(0)

$March
character(0)

$April
character(0)

$May
character(0)

Comment: Interesting, does the `dts` variable after the second variable look right?
Also, what's the size of `myras`? And do they all have the same naming convention?

Comment: The second variable dts works fine, the size of myras is 5465 and all files have the same convention.

Comment: Please try the bigger example and see if it works for you